# Overlay an image with a gif in outlook html email

Tags: html, email, outlook

Im trying to overlay a gif image over a jpeg in html email, but it's not working.

Here is the code im lookuing at:

```
<table id="headerAnimation">
        <!--[if !mso]><!-- -->
        <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td width="600" height="600" align="left" valign="top" style="background:url('/pathtoimage.jpg'); width: 600px;max-width: 600px; height: 594px; min-height: 600px;">
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <img align="center" valign="bottom" id="aniGif" src="/pathtoimage.gif" alt="Campfire season is back" width="140" style="width: 22%;max-width: 22%; position:relative; top: 470px; left:39%;" />
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
        <!--<![endif]-->

        <!--[if mso]>
         <img src="/pathtoimage.jpg" alt="" style="width: 100%;max-width: 600px; height: 594px; min-height: 600px;" />
         <img align="center" valign="bottom" id="aniGif" src="/pathtoimage.gif" alt="Campfire season is back" width="140" style="width: 22%;max-width: 22%; position:relative; margin-top: -125px; left:39%;" />
        <![endif]-->
    </table>
```

In outlook 2003 it works fine, but not 2007 - 2016.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Try this. It displays in Outlook 2013, but the animation will not work in Outlook 2007 and beyond. They just display the first frame. Read up on animated images here:

https://litmus.com/blog/a-guide-to-animated-gifs-in-email

```
<div style="background:#ff0000;" id="headerAnimation">
  <!--[if gte mso 9]>
  <v:background xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" fill="t">
    <v:fill type="tile" src="http://placehold.it/600x600/663399g" color="#7bceeb"/>
  </v:background>
  <![endif]-->
  <table height="100%" width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
    <tr>
      <td valign="top" align="left" background="http://placehold.it/600x600/663399">
        <img id="aniGif" src="https://media.giphy.com/media/1JSjBMZMx41IA/200.gif" alt="Campfire season is back"/>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: I should add animated images do not work in Outlook 2007, 2010 and 2013 and beyond. for more information, visit: https://litmus.com/blog/a-guide-to-animated-gifs-in-email

Comment: Hi @gwally this is aplying to the body of the email. How would I apply it to the div `<div style="background-color:#ff0000;" id="headerAnimation">` Thanks for the help

Comment: In your example, you added the id and I carried that over. You can make the background color any color you like. I just chose red. I also find you might want to use `background: #color;` instead since Outlook sometimes ignores background-color. Or just cut it altogether. I think I messed up adding that.